# Word to describe listing every word vs "counting" (ie, not "enumerate" or "recapitulate")

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

To "[enumerate](https://dictionary.com/browse/enumerate)": `to mention separately as if in counting; name one by one; specify, as in a list`

While it's very *close* to what I'm looking for, I seem to recall a word from either a SAT or GRE prep book I used years ago that was more-or-less "enumerate", but without the "counting" aspect.

For example, what word would you use to describe the list of words/terms that make up a concordance, dictionary, or glossary? They're not *merely* a counted list of words - are they?

I feel like "list" is too generic/imprecise. What word am I looking for?

Comment: Are you looking for the verb to describe the *act* of listing, or the noun to describe the list itself? The question is inconsistent in this regard.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie - either, I suppose: often-enough in English, the same word can be used (with, perhaps, minor modifications (eg adding "to" or ending with "ing")) in multiple parts of speech.

Comment: You could *catalogue* the elements (as a verb), then use that word as a noun to reference the resultant "list". Please provide an *exact context* within which you want to use the verb and/or noun.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't know that I have an "exact context" beyond the three examples I've already listed - "concordance, dictionary, or glossary"

Comment: _Enunciate_ carries the sense 'express in a systematic way', but wouldn't be used for a dictionary word-list.

Comment: By "context", I mean *an example **sentence**, with a "blank" for the sought term*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - then I guess the "example sentence" would be, "I [blanked] the glossary". Something along the lines of "uniquely-verified there was only one instance of a given entry" - but, obviously, *that* isn't a single word :)

Comment: *Each piece of print material developed was [**duplicate checked**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+duplicate+checked+to+determine%22) to determine whether it was already in the ERIC system.* Personally, I'd include a hyphen in that "compound verb", but that's effectively a stylistic choice. Note that this is essentially a situation that barely exists outside of the "computer software" context, so it's not really worth looking for a "normal" verb with the relatively obscure sense required. Which imho effectively makes this question Off Topic anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - glossator would describe the *person* who does what I'm describing (been browsing dictionary.com looking for ideas coincident with this question's existence). If English were consistent, "[to] glossarize" or "glossarizing" or similar would exist.

Comment: No natural language is (or ever *could* be) consistent. But obviously ***to glossarise*** does in fact exist, since you just used it and I understood it perfectly (despite the fact that ***you didn't even spell it right**!* :) You can find [plenty of examples in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22glossarised%22) of that verb being used, and imho it's completely irrelevant that few if any dictionaries would list it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I like how you think I misspelled a word that doesn't exist :). I cannot find said term in any of the dictionaries I've used. Which one did you use that indicated it should have an "s" vs a "z"? FTR - if you sub the "z" for the "s", you find other hits on Google Books.

Comment: I didn't really "think you **misspelt** it" - that was supposed to be a joke! (BrE often uses ***s*** in such contexts where AmE uses ***z***). (And in case you're wondering, I don't think you've ***misspelt** "**misspelled**"* either! :)

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest?

Comment: @Mitch - nothing especially helpful, hence asking here. But now 5 folks decided that this question is "off-topic" ...‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that a concordance is a *[compendium](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compendium)* of terms, in the sense of

> **2 a** a list of a number of items

The dictionary defines *[concordance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concordance)* as "an alphabetical *index* of the principal words in a book," so *index* is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

A ***litany*** is a sizeable list, set, or series, and can be used to describe a list of items or terms which are non-numeric. The term has a somewhat negative connotation, so one might have a litany of things like complaints, grievances, or chores. As far as I know, there isn't a verb form of this word, however.

As mentioned in the comments, ***catalog*** is a more neutral term for a list or set of items. The word when used as a noun refers to simply the collection of items, so a thesaurus or dictionary could be described as a catalog of words. When used as a verb, the word has a connotation of creating the set/collection of items, rather than simply reading from it. One could *enumerate* the amendments to the Constitution simply by reading a list of them aloud, for example, but that wouldn't be typically considered *cataloging* them, unless you were creating your own list for some reason.